# The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/dirk-computer42/c42-backport/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: repository, software-sources

```
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/dirk-computer42/c42-backport/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 5):

That ppa does not support 19.10 (last series was 18.04) and at the top of its page states

> This PPA isn't maintained any more. Please consider removing it from
>   your sources.